# How to exclude import and package statements from IntelliJ's Find results?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to hide all import and packages statements in the results of "Find In Files" (previously "Find in Path") action?

[image]

Comment: You can use Regex for that

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: a regex with a negative look-ahead: `^(?!import).*something`
https://i.ibb.co/LrNpcyy/regex.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others pointed in above comments, using **Regex** seems to be the only viable solution for this scenario.

I used: `^(?!import|package).*wordToSearch`